# How to get last day of last month in unix

Tags: unix, date

I have the requirement to get the last date of the last month.

For today the last months last day is 30 (April).

Comment: `date -d 'last month'`?

Comment: As today is 30th = last day of last month, don't know if it is correct. You can check http://databobjr.blogspot.nl/2011/06/get-first-and-last-day-of-month-in-bash.html

Comment: Thanks working ....@fedorqui

Answer (score 6):

this should work if you have gnu date:

```
1 day ago <month> 1
```

`<month>` here is current month, for example

```
kent$  date -d'1 day ago may 1' 
Tue Apr 30 00:00:00 CEST 2013
```

another example, find the last day of the month before July:

```
kent$  date -d'1 day ago july 1'
Sun Jun 30 00:00:00 CEST 2013
```

note that, the timestamp was set to `00:00:00`.

Comment: +1 I always learn a lot from your answers. What about ` date -d"-1 day 1 $(date +%b)"` to make it more general? Where `%b` outputs May / Apr...

Comment: thank you @fedorqui. and yes, you could say pass the result of another date is more "generic". it is true, you saved typing the current month. but we lost the possibility to pass in a different month as parameter. e.g. my 2nd example. anyway it depends on what do we want to get.

Answer (score 2):

My comment `date -d 'last month'` was wrong.

This works:

```
date -d "-$(date +%d) days -0 month"
```

#### Test

Just changed my date to test this way:

```
$ date
Web May 29 14:06:36 CEST 2013
$ date -d "-$(date +%d) days -0 month"
Tue Apr 30 14:06:36 CEST 2013
```

Reference: http://databobjr.blogspot.nl/2011/06/get-first-and-last-day-of-month-in-bash.html

Answer (score 2):

For KSH/BASH

```
y=$(date '+%Y') # Get current year
m=$(date '+%m') # Get current month
((m--))         # Decrement month
[[ ${m} == 0 ]] && ((y--)) # If month zero, decrement year
[[ ${m} == 0 ]] && m=12    # If month zero, reset to 12

cal ${m} ${y} | awk 'NF{A=$NF}END{print A}'  
# Run cal, and print the last field of the last line with fields.
```

Comment: In Solaris awk had to be substituted with nawk to make it work: cal ${m} ${y} | nawk 'NF{A=$NF}END{print A}'

Answer (score 0):

```
m=`date +%m`
set -A mth Dec Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
prevmth=${mth[$((m - 1))]}


echo $prevmth
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-01) -1 day"
```

It means "Show me the date that is the 1st of the current month minus 1 day"

EDIT:

For MacOS, the args are a bit different

```
date -v-1d +%Y-%m-%d
```

Answer (score 0):

echo $(date -d "$(date +%d) days ago" +%F)

will give the last day of the last month.