# How do I make invalid date to valid in unix?

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

```
While read line 
do 
variable_temp=$line 
tmp_date=`date %Y-%m-"$variable_temp"`               
echo $(date '+%Y-%m-%2d' -d "$tmp_date + 1 month " )
done < ddt.txt
```

The above command throws invalid date error as there is no 31st day in Nov. It works for other dates unlike few exceptional cases like above.

Input file: ddt.txt

Cat ddt.tx

1
2
5
27
29
30
31

Is there any way get resolve the error for 31 ?

It should work for all months.

Comment: Why not start with a valid date literal, if you must type a specific date, then let it be a valid date! "2007-11-30".

Comment: 31 is the value obtained from some commands and I want to get date of next month. I have edited the question with some more info. Can you please check now

Comment: You are still hardcoding (in this case the number 31). Don't do that. Always start with a valid date, regardless of how you derive it.  To find the end of the month, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835145/how-to-get-last-day-of-last-month-in-unix   (otherwise use the many options of the date command, as long as you start with a valid date).

Comment: I do not understand. There is no November 31. Such date doesn't exists. `to solve the above issue ?` What is the issue? It works as intended, it _should_ error on November 31. To solve what exactly? You presented code that doesn't work, but I do not know what is that you want to achieve. If you do not want an error, don't use the code. What should be the output? You want to get a date that is the last day of the next month?

Comment: Yes , there is no nov 31 . I want to get next month 31 in date format . In this case , 31 as dec 31 . For next mnth , 31 should be jan 31 like so . If there is any other solution to get this, it would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: `to get next month 31 in date format` then get the next month and then add 31 to it. Still, February 31 will be invalid.

Comment: I have edited with all requirements. Please check

Comment: If i run in jan on any day , i should get feb working days

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get next month

Why not just:

```
date -d "now +1 month" '+%Y-%m-31'
```